# Is there a need for BPF Linux namespace?

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, linux-namespaces

There are 8 Linux namespaces which isolates PIDs, Network, Users, etc.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html

It allows a namespaced process to have independent PIDs, network devices, users, etc.
They are kernel resources but only visible within one specific namespace.

They are guaranteed to not affect other namespaces.

However I heard that BPF code is not. Once injected in one namespace it has access to everything.

Is there a need for BPF namespace?